# Nexus 4 3G not working

Tags: nexus-4, mobile-data, mobile-network

The phone is running AOSP Marshmallow, it is rooted and has Xposed installed. Mobile operator is Latvian Mobile Phone with working data plan. I can send and receive calls and texts and use WiFi.

So far I've tried:

- Turning radio on and off - failed
- Rebooting - failed
- Rebooting in safe mode - failed
- Going to lollipop stock image - failed
- Going to jellybean stock image - failed
- Flashing radios - failed
- Checking APN at the service center - failed
- Replacing the SIM card - failed
- Doing all the stuff mentioned above with the new SIM card - failed